# cannot reinitialize datatable error popup and center aligning datatable

Tags: php, css, datatable

how to get over this popup error "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"

also, i want to center align table how do i do this ?

i've tried methods given on datatables website but it wont solve anything
what will happen if i ignore this error ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UIT-RGPV</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Alloted Room</td>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'data');

                            $sql = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM user');
                            while($data = $sql->fetch_array()) {
                                echo '
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>'.$data['id'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$data['fname'].'</td>

                                    </tr>
                                ';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".table").DataTable();

</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".table").DataTable({
                "ordering": true,
                "searching": true,
                "paging": true,
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": 0,
                        "searchable": false,
                        "visible": true
                    }
                ],
                "order": [[2, "desc"]]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make centre align table but its aligned on the left side and i want to get over that popup error.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
<script>
 $(".table").DataTable();
</script>
```

from your code and add `style="margin: 0 auto;"` to your table to make the table at center of the page, if you need the content have to center aligned means use `style="text-align: center;"`, if both aligned to be in center means just use `style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;"`

Comment: hi! thanks for your response but if i remove any of
<script>
 $(".table").DataTable();
</script>

   OR
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          ..........
        });
    </script>
search and page scroll features go away it converts into normal table

Comment: you may not initialize the datatable twice as per your current code, and i just cant able to understand what is the problem with your code, kindly check this out https://datatables.net/manual/installation